# Using Jquery to hide and show a div section

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to start out saying that I am new to asp .net and html coding. I have a asp .net user control that I am dynamically placing on a page.

The user control looks something like this:

```
<div style="background-color:#EFEFEF;">
    <div style="float: left; vertial-align:middle;">
        <asp:Image ID="ImageExpandColaspe" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="PFDStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; vertical-align:middle;">
       <asp:button ID="PFDSelect" runat-"server" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div> 
<div ID="PFDDetails">This is a test</div>
```

This user control is placed on the page dynamically several times.

I am so new to jquery and ajax and asp .net that I am not sure how to do the following:

When the user clicks the ImageExpandColapse
1) Change the image from one image to another
2) Toggle the PFDetails div from either visible to hide or vice versa

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the click event of your Image to toggle the div you want to show/hide:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= ImageExpandColaspe.ClientID %>").click(function() {
      $("<%= PFDetails.ClientID %>").toggle();  
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You have a typo, that won't work.  You need to have a `#` on your `Click` event.  Also your toggle won't work, because the View Engine will change the ID for that button it should be: `$('#<%= PFDetails.ClientID %>')`

Answer (score 0):

Put the attribute `id` at the `div` that you want to hide and use: `$('#yourId').hide()`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that, just remember when you use `runat="server"` the *View Engine* will render and modify your tag.  So to ensure your jQuery triggers those tags you would do:

```
$('#<%= txtExample.ClientID %>').hide();
```

To correctly grab the element, you have to tell the *View Engine* to place the proper `ClientID` in that location, so the jQuery selector can correctly grab your element.